# Rigify rig overwrites my other rigify rig from a separate skeleton

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

Potentially helpful info: I copied the bones of a metarig and separated them in edit mode. Then, I renamed them the same as the original rig. The original rig has 'ORG.' before every bone name unlike the copied rig.

If restarting is the easiest method, please tell me if there is a way to teleport the bones of the new metarig to the old metarig in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Before generating the new rig, use advanced option to choose not to overwrite, and generate a new rig with a new name instead.

[image]

Comment: I did all that before posting this question, and got the error: Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "lips.R" not found'
I've never seen such bone on the human metarig model.